# App rejected in beta release

Tags: android, performance, android-studio, google-play-services, android-build

when I upload my build for beta release, every time I got App rejected from google play and the reason is:

> Your app is using a version of libpng containing a security vulnerability. Please see this Google Help Center article for details, including the deadline for fixing the vulnerability.

Email

> Hello Google Play Developer,
>
> We rejected xxxx, with package name com.xxxx.xx, for violating our Malicious Behavior or User Data policy. If you submitted an update, the previous version of your app is still available on Google Play.
>
> This app uses software that contains security vulnerabilities for users or allows the collection of user data without proper disclosure.
>
> Below is the list of issues and the corresponding APK versions that were detected in your recent submission. Please upgrade your app(s) as soon as possible and increment the version number of the upgraded APK.

Comment: What is it about those messages that is unclear? They seem exceedingly clear to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure of the version of libpng that you are using. As suggested by [google help center](https://support.google.com/faqs/answer/7011127?hl=en), please migrate your app(s) to libpng v1.0.66, v.1.2.56, v.1.4.19, v1.5.26 or higher as soon as possible and increment the version number of the upgraded APK.

> Beginning Sep 17, 2016, Google Play will block publishing of any new apps or updates that use vulnerable versions of libpng. Your published app version will remain unaffected, however any updates to the app will be blocked unless they address this vulnerability.